# Excel formula showed as '=#NULL' returns correct result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file, in that file I have plenty of formulas and ALL seem to do what they suppose to, give the results.

Now the weird part, I have found that some(few) cells instead of showing in formula bar original formula like `=SUM(A1:A5)` are now showing formula like `=#NULL!`.

However in cell it self result is displayed and it is correct result, recalculated with each change in sheet.
I had a backup copy of that file, I have copied formulas over and everything seemed fine until day after. When file was reopened issue has returned.

Have anyone have any idea how to sort out that mystery?

[image]

Edit: 
Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Formulas are working and calculating correctly.
The issue lies in showing formula it self, formula bar isn't showing formula used for calculation, instead it is showing `=#NULL!` formula in formula bar.

Please see picture with 'Show Formula' enabled. All cells showing `=#NULL!` should actual formulas used for calculation.
Look specially at formula bar it self.

[image: Excel - Show formula enabled view]

Comment: The error is  #NULL! Errors – Incorrectly Separated Cell References, so I guess first check for this using formula auditing tools. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/correct-a-null-error-c08ed643-ef4d-4735-bc74-f29296632f0d

Comment: @QHarr That is not and issue, please see edit in OP

Comment: Anyone?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive answer without actually seeing all your formulas, but generally the `#NULL!` error appears when *(according to documentation)*:

> This error occurs when you specify an intersection of two areas that do not intersect. The intersection operator is a space character between references.

Most common issues (I'll use formula `=SUM()` since you used it in your original question, but this doesn't exclusively apply to it)

`=SUM(A3 A6)`

`=SUM(A1:A5, B1:B5)`

`=SUM(A1, #REF!)`

> #REF! is commonly caused if you are referencing to a cell, that from
>   to a different worksheet that is no longer available, or the reference
>   is no longer correct altogether`

So to sum it up *(no pun intended)* check up if your formulas have correct seperators (`,`) or (`;`). Check if your formulas make sense (eg. you can't sum two ranges, use `=SUBTOTAL()`instead) and check if your cell references are still correct.

Comment: The issue isn't the result it self, this one is returned correctly. Only formula in formula bar it self is showed as different formula '=#NULL!'. So I can't check what formula actually is.

Comment: @LeszekJ Then your issue is probably caused by incorrectly copy-pasting data and that's not something people at Stack can help you with. Just rewrite the formnula then, if you're certain that you're not doing errors anywhere else like I suggested